# Saving active directory users background photo and applying it when they log on

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

On my active directory domain, I am trying to work out how to save the users background photo and then have it be applied every time they log on on any pc.
Thanks for the help,
Matt

Comment: What about writing a logoff script that would save the picture to a network disk and then logon script that would check the folder and apply the picture if necessary?